# Inverse Power Iteration converges to largest eigenvalue instead of smallest?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matlab

I am trying to write a Matlab function that takes a matrix and an iteration count and performs inverse power iteration to output the smallest eigenvalue. The problem is, as k increases, the function converges to the largest eigenvalue of A instead of the smallest. My code is:

```
function eigval = invpowerit (A, k, start)
  if ~exist('start', 'var')
    start = ones(size(A, 1), 1);
  end
  eigvec = start;
  for n = 1:k
    w = A\eigvec;
    normw = norm(w);
    eigvec = w/normw;
  end
  eigval = 1/normw;
```

I can't figure out where I have applied the method incorrectly.

Comment: So for $A=\begin{pmatrix}7&0\\0&2\end{pmatrix}$ you get $7$, not $2$?

Comment: Actually for that matrix it seems to converge to 2, so perhaps this algorithm is working properly. However, when I tested it with the matrix $A = \left(\begin{array}{cc} 3 & 1 \\ 1 & 3 \end{array}\right)$ I got 4 instead of 2. Any idea why this is?

Answer (score 3):

Your are unlucky with your choice of starting vector, $(1,1)^T$. This happens to be an eigenvector of $\begin{pmatrix} 3 & 1 \\ 1 & 3 \end{pmatrix}$, so the iteration is stuck in that eigenspace and returns the corresponding eigenvalue ($4$), regardless of what other eigenvalues the matrix may have.

To avoid this issue,  begin with a random vector: `start = rand(size(A, 1), 1);`